# Math writing tablet apps instead of LaTeX

Tags: math, documentation-generator, ipad-app, latex

I am not fluent in LaTeX and was wondering whether any of the new iPad *pen-input* apps are very useful for writing math documents more fluently than using LaTeX as a proxy language. If so, which one/ones do you use for that, and do you ultimately export to some standard tool or actually get the whole thing final within the app?

Hope this kind of question well fits this site.

Answer (score 1):

I'd pick up [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). It's a much easier formatting language and LaTeX can be generated from it, e.g. with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).

I am using [Emacs](https://emacsformacosx.com/) as a markdown and LaTeX editor (with [AucTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/download.html)), but agree that it's not everyones' choice. I'd look into [Typora](https://typora.io) for markdown, it is cross-plattform, but not available on iDevices. There are some [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/typora/?platform=ipad), though.

Comment: Most markdown implementations I've seen don't provide any support for mathematical notation.

Comment: Oh, well. You just escape to TeX every time you feel so or don't remember the proper markdown syntax. It easier to write `_emphasis_` than `\emph{emphasis}`, but at least pandoc would detect `$$\int e^{\frac{1}{x}} dx$$` _and_ convert it to a proper LaTeX display chant.

Comment: I would call that "using LaTeX as a proxy language", which is what the OP specifically said they don't want.  (I suppose it's possible they meant something else, though.)